# React Js If Else using data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, ecmascript-6, jsx

This data.quotes.USD.percent_change_1h is take data from API, and i need it to check if it includes "-" (a minus sign). If it contain minus sign, the color of data number from the API would be red, if not, the color will be green. But somehow, my code dosen't work

```
class Cointable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      data: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(
      () =>
        fetch(conf[this.props.coin].url)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(
            result => {
              this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                data: result.data,
              })
            },
            error => {
              this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                error,
              })
            }
          ),
      5000
    )
  }
render(){
const { error, isLoaded, data } = this.state
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
return(
```

//this is where the main problem is

```
  {data.quotes.USD.percent_change_1h.includes('-') === true ? (
    <TD style={{ color: 'red' }}>{data.quotes.USD.percent_change_1h}</TD>
                  ) : (
    <TD style={{ color: 'green' }}>{data.quotes.USD.percent_change_1h}</TD>
                  )}
)
}
```

it makes my table all gone and wont show anything. The value of percent_change_1h something like "0.7" or "-0.7"

Comment: Could you add a little more code or context?

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a very helpful description. What happens? Are there any error messages? Provide a [mcve]. What value does `percent_change_1h` have?

Comment: it makes my table all gone and wont show anything. The value of percent_change_1h something like "0.7" or "-0.7"

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this:

```
data.quotes.USD.percent_change_1h.indexOf('-') > -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is initialized as array in constructor. Is it corect? Btw. Includes return boolean by default. The check for value true in ternary operator is redundant. Btw it seems corect so i guess there is some problem with ur data?

Comment: yeah. if i did not check it, the data return just fine. I just need it to change color by the value.

Answer (score 0):

Check these two things..

1. type of data.quotes.USD.percent_change_1h must be a string
2. Most of the IE versions will not support includes(), so check your code in other browsers if you are doing in IE

Comment: I tried using data.quotes.USD.percent_change_1h.toString().indexOf('-') it still wont work

Answer (score 0):

Did you open the console?
You probably have an error because you're fetching data and then trying to use it before it is set.
Also, you're initialising data as an array and then using it as an object. If data is an array of objects, I suggest you to create an auxiliary render method and using the `map()` method.

Something like this:

```
renderData = () => {
    return this.state.data.map(item => { 
        return (
        item.quotes.USD.percent_change_1h.includes('-')
            ? <TD style={{ color: 'red' }}>{item.quotes.USD.percent_change_1h}</TD>
            : <TD style={{ color: 'green' }}>{item.quotes.USD.percent_change_1h}</TD>
        )
    })
}
```

And then in your main render() method call it like this 
`{this.renderData()}`.